# Ponteiro para array de ponteiros

Tags: c, c++

Gostaria de saber se no código abaixo (a variável 'p') é um Ponteiro para um Array de Ponteiros ?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

double valor = 7;
double *balance[5] = {&valor, &valor, &valor, &valor, &valor};
double **p;

p = balance;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta para sua pergunta é sim, quando você fez `double **p` você criou uma variável que é ponteiro de um ponteiro de `double`. Quando for acessar o valor de `P`, use `*p[índice]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main (void)
{
    double valor = 7.0;
    double *balance[5] = {&valor, &valor, &valor, &valor, &valor};
    double **p;
 
    p = balance;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%lf\n",*p[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/nG97vq).